# Helper for Many-to-Many Form

Tags: django, django-forms, code-reuse

If you have a `ManyToManyField` with few entries, the Django Admin interface is good.

But if there are a lot of rows, you can't display all as HTML select-Input.

I dream of a django `FormField` which gives me two ways for the input.

Example: Edit the groups of a user (imagine that there thousands of groups)

- autocomplete: search some attributes of the other model (in this case `Group`).
- PopUp with search form: Create a search form and choose some of the matching lines.

I think this could be implemented with in a generic way, so that you can *use* this Field without much coding.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start is using the [raw_id_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields) option on your admin definitions. There is no huge HTML list being passed to the browser and it has a pop-up search for adding an objects.